# Angular 2 Add input values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I add the values ​​entered in an input

This is my HTML,
But I do not know if I should write something in the ts

```html
<div class="small-7 columns">
  <md-input-container>
    <input type="number" id="fnum" placeholder="fnum">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <input type="number" id="snum" placeholder="snum">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container>
    <input disabled>{{ (snum) + (fnum) }}
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: You should use ngModel: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngModel` to get the `input` values and `ngModelChange` for change detection. Then, add them in your `ts` and update a third variable that holds the addition.

html:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="number" id="fnum" placeholder="fnum" 
           [(ngModel)]="fnum" (ngModelChange)="addNums()">
</md-input-container>

<p></p>

<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="number" id="snum" placeholder="snum" 
           [(ngModel)]="snum" (ngModelChange)="addNums()">
</md-input-container>

<p></p>  

<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput disabled>{{ total }}
</md-input-container>
```

In ts:

```
fnum: number = 0;
snum: number = 0;

total: number = 0;

addNums(){
  this.total = this.fnum + this.snum;
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/0RlO9LeWiIMFOyYyYGxP?p=preview)

Comment: This is the correct one :). Also, It's worth to mention that the OP is missing one of the most important things: `mdInput` on `<input>`. [Here's a version without `ngModel`](https://plnkr.co/edit/prEmPRiVqAdcRL9D6uOo?p=info).

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been helped